# Intellij 2019.3.1 - disable wrapping in Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, variable-assignment, word-wrap

When I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to reformat a file, Intellij wraps lines when should not.

I expect this **not to change**:

```
List<Something> somethings = somethingsMap.getOrDefault(key, Collections.emptyList());
```

But it changes to:

```
List<Something> somethings =
            somethingsMap.getOrDefault(key, Collections.emptyList());
```

This are my settings:

- Hard wrap at: 140
- [image: Assignment]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Omg I got it!
I had Eclipse Code Formatter plugin installed.
And It was messing with me.